# Combine multiple MySQL queries returning different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm getting data from 4 different tables using 3 different mysql queries and JOINS.

MySQL Query 1

```
SELECT tb1.request_item_id AS most_requested_item_id, tb2.item_name AS most_requested_item_name
FROM  `requests` tb1 
LEFT JOIN `items` tb2 ON tb1.request_item_id = tb2.item_id
GROUP BY tb1.request_item_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Query 1 Output

```
  most_requested_item_id | most_requested_item_name
         87              | Poster FLS
         95              | Sample Item 4
         89              | Earth
```

Query 2

```
  SELECT tb1.user_credit AS highest_credit_value, tb1.user_full_name AS highest_credit_user 
  FROM users tb1 
  ORDER BY tb1.user_credit 
  DESC LIMIT 3
```

Query 2 output

```
   highest_credit_value | highest_credit_user
          140           | User A
          11            | User B
          10            | User C
```

Query 3

```
SELECT tb1.credit_user_id AS credit_monthly_user, 
       SUM(tb1.credit_amount) AS totalCredit_monthly, 
       tb2.user_full_name AS monthly_credit_user 
FROM `credit_log` tb1 
LEFT JOIN users tb2 ON tb1.credit_user_id = tb2.user_id 
WHERE tb1.credit_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY credit_user_id 
ORDER BY totalCredit_monthly DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Query 3 Output

```
     credit_monthly_user | totalCredit_monthly Descending 1 | monthly_credit_user
     User C              | 350                              | User D
     User E              | 170                              | User F
     User G              | 70                               | User H
```

My SQL query

```
(SELECT tb1.request_item_id AS most_requested_item_id, tb2.item_name AS most_requested_item_name
FROM  `requests` tb1 LEFT JOIN `items` tb2
ON tb1.request_item_id = tb2.item_id
GROUP BY tb1.request_item_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT tb1.user_credit AS highest_credit_value, tb1.user_full_name AS highest_credit_user
FROM users tb1
ORDER BY tb1.user_credit DESC
LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT tb1.credit_user_id AS credit_monthly_user, SUM(tb1.credit_amount) AS totalCredit_monthly, tb2.user_full_name AS monthly_credit_user
FROM `credit_log` tb1 LEFT JOIN users tb2 
ON tb1.credit_user_id = tb2.user_id
WHERE tb1.credit_date
BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY credit_user_id 
ORDER BY totalCredit_monthly 
DESC LIMIT 3)
```

**Desired Output**

```
   most_requested_item_id | most_requested_item_name | highest_credit_value | highest_credit_user | credit_monthly_user | totalCredit_monthly Descending 1 | monthly_credit_user
          87              | Poster FLS               | 140                  | User A              |  User C             | 350                              | User D
          95              | Sample Item 4            | 11                   | User B              | User E              | 170                              | User F
          89              | Earth                    | 10                   | User C              | User G              | 70                               | User H
```

But I get an error:

> The used select statements have a different number of columns union

Schema of table **credit_log**

```
  Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default| Extra
  credit_log_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL   | auto_increment
  credit_user_id| varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL   |
  credit_date   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL   |
  credit_amount | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL   |
  credit_type   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL   |
  credit_desc   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL   |
```

Schema of table **requests**

```
  Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra
  request_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              |  auto_increment
  request_requser_id   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI
  request_item_id      | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI
  request_status       | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | Active
  request_lastmodified | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  request_message      | varchar(225) | YES  |     | NULL
```

Schema of table **items**

```
  Field                   | Type         | Null | Key     | Default           | Extra
  item_id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI     | NULL              | auto_increment
  item_name               | varchar(255) | NO   |         | NULL
  item_category           | varchar(255) | NO   |         | NULL
  item_desc               | varchar(255) | YES  |         | NULL
  item_user_id            | varchar(255) | YES  |         | NULL
  item_lease_value        | int(11)      | YES  |         | NULL
  item_lease_term         | varchar(255) | YES  |         | NULL
  item_image              | mediumtext   | YES  |         | NULL
  item_primary_image_link | varchar(255) | YES  |         | NULL
  item_status             | varchar(255) | NO   | Created |
  item_uid                | varchar(255) | YES  |         | NULL
  item_lat                | float(10,6)  | YES  |         | NULL
  item_lng                | float(10,6)  | YES  |         | NULL
  item_lastmodified       | datetime     | NO             | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Schema of table **users**.

[image: users_table]

Is there any way of combining the above 3 queries into one so that it returns total 7 columns?? Please help

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you post table schema and desire result ?

Comment: while not required, posting a link to a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) can be very advantageous for problems like this.

Comment: Just asking, do the tables have foreign keys?

Comment: You do not need a union query (vertical stacking) but a join of all selects (horizontal merging). However, the only connecting tissue I see is at `user` level. How do *requests* and *items* relate to *users* table?

Comment: So you just want 3 unrelated results combined as one? Do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @jarlh  Yes they are unrelated results..how do I do that in mysql??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider joining all queries by row number or rank. Since they are all unrelated pieces, we can match by their row position which they would share. Below runs queries as derived tables joined together in outer main query.

Specifically, first two derived tables use correlated count subqueries while last uses a defined variable (as last is more complex since ordering is run on an aggregate value unlike others). If count aggregates do not work, use variable for all. And `LEFT JOIN` over `INNER JOIN` is used in case ranks do not match across and rows with NULLs will appear where you can adjust rank calculations accordingly. Right now, each queries' *rank* outputs. Ties may be an issue too.

```
SELECT main1.*, main2.*, main3.*
FROM
  (SELECT r.request_item_id AS most_requested_item_id, i.item_name AS most_requested_item_name,
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM `requests` sub 
           WHERE sub.request_item_id >= r.request_item_id) AS rank
   FROM `requests` r 
   LEFT JOIN `items` i ON r.request_item_id = i.item_id
   GROUP BY r.request_item_id, i.item_name
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 3) main1

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT u.user_credit AS highest_credit_value, u.user_full_name AS highest_credit_user,        
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM `users` sub 
           WHERE sub.user_credit >= u.user_credit) AS rank
   FROM `users` u
   ORDER BY u.user_credit DESC
   LIMIT 3) main2
ON main1.rank = main2.rank

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT c.credit_user_id AS credit_monthly_user, SUM(c.credit_amount) AS totalCredit_monthly,
           u.user_full_name AS monthly_credit_user,
           (@rownum:= @rownum + 1) AS rank
   FROM `credit_log` c, (select @rownum := 0) sqlvars,
   LEFT JOIN `users` u ON c.credit_user_id = u.user_id
   WHERE c.credit_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
   GROUP BY c.credit_user_id, u.user_full_name
   ORDER BY totalCredit_monthly DESC 
   LIMIT 3) main3
ON main1.rank = main3.rank
```